# hosting asp.net pages within the app

Tags: asp.net, hosting, reporting, cassini

The goal is to generate some html reports and html emails using templates hosted within the app perhaps using cassini

so the report files will be saved in 
app_home\Report\Templates*.MyReport 
file

The app would allow a report (.aspx) page to be selected, loads it using cassini/asp.net hosting api processing some custom markup to populate the data

the resultant html can be viewed in the webbrowser control or can be emailed as html emails

Is there a better way ?
Also any pointers on using cassini as such would be great

Comment: You'll need a few more paragraphs of detail if you want any responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>AFAIK you can not distribute Cassini with your apps. There are other desktop webserver, but non of them are 100% compatible with asp.net
In my opinion, your solution will be too complicated to implement.</s>

### Edit

I learn [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916568/asp-net-mvc-render-page-to-a-file/918090#918090) that

> I personally like the StringTemplate option mentioned above, but you can actually host the ASP.NET runtime in a desktop application.
>
> Rick Strahl over at [West Wind Technologies](http://www.west-wind.com) has a detailed example of how to set it up:  [Using the ASP.Net Runtime for extending desktop applications with dynamic HTML Scripts](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/aspnetruntime/aspnetruntime.asp)
>
> Here are a couple of other examples:
>
> - [Code Project: Using ASP.NET Runtime in Desktop Applications](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/usingaspruntime.aspx)
> - [MSDN Magazine: ASP. NET Client-side Hosting with Cassini](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188791.aspx) -- The nuts and bolts of how to use the ApplicationHost class.
> - [Andrew Peter's Blog: In-process ASP.NET MVC Web Form View Rendering](http://andrewpeters.net/2008/11/19/in-process-aspnet-mvc-web-form-view-rendering/)

## Other alternatives

### Alternative 1

One simple solution would be making simple replacements in the template HTML (using you own processor, and you will be ready to go.

Something like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Phone</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>$Name</th> <!-- you should run a replace with $Name to the name -->
  <th>$Phone</th>
</tr>
```

### Alternative 2

Use a templating engine like [StringTemplate](http://stringtemplate.org/) (look for the C# implementation). [This CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/codegen/DotNetCodeGeneration.aspx) is a good intro to the subject

### Alternative 3

If you want something more advanced (if your users can take it) I would investigate adding scripting to your app (IronPhyton, IronRuby)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use xslt for such tasks - you can serialize you data model into an xml document then you can transform xml document with an xsl template into html.

Comment: the goal is to offload the template generation to the moderately computer/html literate end user who can format their own reports with says word ergo, xslt won't work