# c# how to get a stream processed by httpResponse.BinaryWrite

Tags: asp.net, httpresponse, nmock

I have the following method that writes a stream in a HttpResponse object.

```
public HttpResponse ShowPDF(Stream stream)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = (MemoryStream) stream;

        httpResponse.Clear();
        httpResponse.Buffer = true;
        httpResponse.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        httpResponse.BinaryWrite(memoryStream.ToArray());
        httpResponse.End();

        return httpResponse;

    }
```

In order to test it, I need to recover the processed stream.
Is there someway to read the stream from the httpResponse object?

Comment: is httpResponse declared outside of this method?

Comment: @betogrun: Which mocking framework do you use for testing?

Comment: @LostHobbit yes it is. I´m using a fake HttpContextBase from [here](http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/aanttila/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=552eb137-35b0-44f9-bee8-641e08159e2b&ID=27&Web=f31077d6-bea7-416f-82e9-e4103a9c0670).
I was using NMock3 mocking framework, but the mock doesn´t return the object, it just checks the expectations.

Comment: @SLaks - unfortunately HttpResponse doesn't actually inherit from HttpResponseBase

Comment: @LostHobbit: Yes; he'll need to change his code to use HttpResponseBase.

Comment: @SLaks, I can´t use mocks once I need the stream within in the httpResponse object. NMocks returns only empty objects.

Comment: it's straight from System.Object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.aspx

Comment: @SLaks - Currently I´m using HttpResponseBase.

Comment: Is there someway to get the stream from the httpResponse object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two ideas... one to mock the HttpResponse, and the other is to simulate a web server.

**1. Mocking HttpResponse**

I wrote this before I knew which mocking framework you used.  Here's how you could test your method using TypeMock.

This assumes that you pass your httpResponse variable to the method, changing the method as follows:

```
public void ShowPDF(Stream stream, HttpResponse httpResponse)
```

Of course you would change this to passing it to a property on your Page object instead, if it is a member of your Page class.

And here's an example of how you could test using a fake HttpResponse:

```
internal void TestPDF()
{
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("C:\\deleteme\\The Mischievous Nerd's Guide to World Domination.pdf", FileMode.Open);
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    try
    {
        memoryStream.SetLength(fileStream.Length);
        fileStream.Read(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fileStream.Length);

        memoryStream.Flush();
        fileStream.Close();

        byte[] buffer = null;

        var fakeHttpResponse = Isolate.Fake.Instance<HttpResponse>(Members.ReturnRecursiveFakes);
        Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeHttpResponse.BinaryWrite(null)).DoInstead((context) => { buffer = (byte[])context.Parameters[0]; });

        ShowPDF(memoryStream, fakeHttpResponse);

        if (buffer == null)
            throw new Exception("It didn't write!");
    }
    finally
    {
        memoryStream.Close();
    }        
}
```

**2. Simulate a Web Server**

Perhaps you can do this by simulating a web server.  It might sound crazy, but it doesn't look like it's that much code.  Here are a couple of links about running Web Forms outside of IIS.

[Can I run a ASPX and grep the result without making HTTP request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394724/can-i-run-a-aspx-and-grep-the-result-without-making-http-request)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163879.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer Lost Hobbit, but I can´t use TypeMock. The only approved framowemork I´m allowed to use is NMock.

Comment: @betogrun Pity... perhaps tag your post with NMock... maybe an NMock expert will find it.

Comment: Sure! I´ve just edited the post.
I´ll try to apply your example using NMock
Thanks!

Comment: @betogrun - I added another idea to my answer, in case it helps.

Comment: Thanks again @Lost Hobbit!
I´ll try this approach too!